# Entity Framework code-first working with local DB, but errors when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I have developed a project usein Asp.Net Web API, followint the Entity Framework **code-first** approach.

I have tested it in local machine with a local DB in Visual Studio 2013 and it works correctly.

The problem comes when I replace the connection string and deploy the DB to Azure. I'm able to perform some queries, but not other.

For example if I enter in the browser `http://my-site/api/users/1` I get the expected result. However the query `http://my-site/api/users/` return me an error related to Json serialization:

```
{ "$id" : "1",
  "ExceptionMessage" : "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
  "ExceptionType" : "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "InnerException" : { "$id" : "2",
      "ExceptionMessage" : "Error getting value from 'Devices' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_50420314CCDC05AAF3288A574C1CBB8436C09BAEF7539C2795445FCBA161AC99'.",
      "ExceptionType" : "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
      "InnerException" : { "$id" : "3",
          "ExceptionMessage" : "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.",
          "ExceptionType" : "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
          "InnerException" : { "$id" : "4",
              "ExceptionMessage" : "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.",
              "ExceptionType" : "System.InvalidOperationException",
              "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
              "StackTrace" : "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"
            },
          "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
          "StackTrace" : "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_50420314CCDC05AAF3288A574C1CBB8436C09BAEF7539C2795445FCBA161AC99.get_Devices()\r\n   at GetDevices(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"
        },
      "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
      "StackTrace" : "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__19.MoveNext()"
    },
  "Message" : "An error has occurred.",
  "StackTrace" : null
}
```

This problem is really annoying me, because as I mentioned, with the local DB works fine. The databases generated locally and in Azure seems equal. So, I can't guess where the problem could be.

Comment: Is the data confirmed as equivalent in the two databases? It could be an issue only showing up due to different data. Also, can you post the relevant code for User and Device entities, plus the fluent API configuration if there is any?

Comment: I don't have the code now, but `User` has a `Devices` property of type `ICollection<Device>`. `Device` has a property of type `User` too. i.e. Each devices has a user, while one user can own many devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding .ToArray() to the result I was returning from my GetAll() method solved the problem:

```
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToArray();
    }
```

But, I'm still wondering why it was working with the local DB and not with the DB deployed to Azure.

Adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` also solved my issue. But since I don't really know what does enabling that feature entail, I opted for the first option.

Comment: Yeap. .ToArray() , .ToList(), .Single() , all this will return objects. What you can't return is a entity framework proxy. I suggest you map to POCO to avoid that, but returning that way will work too.

Comment: MultipleActiveResultSets is necessary when you have child objects that are being lazy-loaded. This allows EF to have one result set open (for your parent objects) and open new result sets to get the child objects.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is what the error message tells you. It cannot serialize Entity Framework Proxy to JSON. You should map to POCO classes and return them:

```
//poco
    public class PersonPoco
    {
       public string FirstName {get;set;}
       public string LastName {get;set;}
    }
```

//controller

```
public IEnumerable<PersonPoco> Get()
{
    var person = _personRepository.FindAll();

    person.Select(x=> new PersonPoco() {
     FirstName = x.f_name,
     LastName = x.l_name
    }).ToList();
}
```

you can use AutoMapper to do this conversion, you can create Extension methods to do this conversion. Anyway, it's just a sample.

Comment: I will check tomorrow if this is the problem. But, then, why does it work when I use a local DB?

Comment: good question. I'm almost sure that it won't work locally too.

Comment: This is why I wonder if it's data related. If the query returned no data on the localdb, then there would be no serialization error. Another solution, by the way, is to turn off dynamic proxies and use explicit `.Include` statements.